# Why doesn't my Python comparator work?

Tags: python

My code is as follows:

```
data = [["456"], ["123"], ["987", "234"]]
def comparator(array1, array2):
    return array1[0] > array2[0]
data.sort(comparator)
print data
```

I'm trying to sort based on the first value in the array. The output is:

```
[['456'], ['123'], ['987', '234']]
```

Why doesn't my function sort the array of arrays?

Comment: what is array1 and array 2?

Comment: @ADITYA They're the lists inside the list passed to the function by `sort`...

Comment: Why should it work? What did you expect sorting a function?

Comment: It will not work

Comment: @abccd What do you mean "sorting a function object"...?

Comment: @ Mary it will be better to collect all ur items in a list and simply call the sort method based on the operator.itemgetter on your first element

Comment: How do you want to sort the arrays?

Comment: What is your expected result for this input?

Comment: That's not how comparators work. You must return a negative, zero, or positive number to indicate if the value is smaller than, equal, or greater than the other value. Convert the elements to integers and try `int(array1[0]) - int(array2[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

> In Py3.0, the cmp parameter was removed entirely (as part of a larger
> effort to simplify and unify the language, eliminating the conflict
> between rich comparisons and the **cmp** methods).
>
> In Py2.x, sort allowed an optional function which can be called for
> doing the comparisons. That function should take two arguments to be
> compared and then return a **negative value for less-than, return
> zero if they are equal, or return a positive value for greater-than**.

so you can try this:

```
data=[['123'], ['45'], ['987', '234']]
def comparator(array1, array2):
    return int(array1[0]) - int(array2[0])
data.sort(comparator)
print data
```

Or another way:

```
>>> data=[['123'], ['45'], ['987', '234']]
>>> data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
>>> data
[['45'], ['123'], ['987', '234']]
```